# What is the FASTEST way to calculate the Pearson coefficient between all columns in a large and sparse matrix?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pearson-correlation, recommendation-engine

### Background

I got a sparse dataset, like [Amazon Review Data](http://jmcauley.ucsd.edu/data/amazon/). I'd like to calculate the PCC(Pearson Correlation Coefficient) between all columns and save it for later reuse. However, it is time-consuming to get the result.

For example, the matrix has approximate 800k columns and 300k rows, but for each column, only two or three rows have values while others are 0s (missing value).

Is it possible to get the PCC matrix within a reasonable period of time?

### What I've tried

I'm using **Python** to do this job.
The methods I've tried include:

  1.

```
import pandas as pd

# Gets the sparse DataFrame
dfs = pd.DataFrame(...)

# dfs.shape is (300k, 800k)

pcc = dfs.corr()

# save pcc
```

2.

```py
# Transfers `dfs` to dense DataFrame dfd
# Format: (column_id, row_id, value)

vals = dfd.values
col_ids = np.unique(vals[:, 0]).tolist()

# Get all of the combinations between column indices.
# However, It takes about 2 BILLION iterations.
for i, j in combinations(col_ids, 2):
    # Get matrix of col_id equals `i` and `j`
    i_val = vals[vals[:, 0] == i]
    j_val = vals[vals[:, 0] == j]

    # Calc PCC of `i_val` and `j_val`
    pcc = pcc(i_val, j_val)
# Save all `pcc` into a matrix
```

In python, I used a single process and a single thread to simulate to execute `for loop` like:

```py
import progressbar
import time

total = 2000000000
for i in progressbar.progressbar(range(total)):
    time.sleep(0.005) # The actual time is much larger than 0.005s
```

It will cost about **200 DAYS**...

### Any solutions?

Therefore, could you help me to solve this problem or give me another angle to think about it?

Thank you for **200 DAYS**!

Comment: Maybe divide your dataset (Number of CPU core) times and run PCC on each of them in a separate thread.

Comment: @hacker315 Thanks for your comments, I finally decided to reduce the size of the matrix by setting thresholds to filter the too small sub-groups.